# CNSaveRequest returns "Updated Record Does Not Exist"

Tags: ios, ios9, cncontact

The code I'm debugging tries to save a contact to Contacts.app via the new CNContacts framework in iOS 9. However it fails and returns this error. The code isn't updating a record but rather it is trying to create a new one. Why and I getting this error?

> Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=200 "Updated Record Does Not Exist"
>   UserInfo={CNInvalidRecordIdentifiers=(
>       ... ), NSLocalizedDescription=Updated Record Does Not Exist,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The save request failed because it updates a
>   record that does not exist or has already been deleted.}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code was trying to save a contact with an identifier obtained from a new `CNMutableContact` instead of using `nil` for the default container.

```
[saveRequest addContact:mutContact toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];
```